# Display template conditional format

Tags: sharepoint-online, display-template

I've been working on a display template to format a timeline.

Right now I'm working on conditional formatting to show icons for each content type shown in the timeline. The conditional works fine as long as I use a value without a space in it like: 'Invoice' but it doesn't work when I use the value 'White Paper'.

```
<!--#_ if(ContentType == "Invoice") { _#-->
<div class="timeline_card_doc">Invoice</div>
<!--#_ } if(ContentType == "White Paper") { _#-->
<div class="timeline_card_doc">White Paper</div>
<!--#_ } _#-->
```

Comment: Try to add "%20" instead of the whitespaces as this is how SharePoint handles spaces. Test using "White%20Paper".

Comment: Replacing the whitespace with "%20" doesn't seem to work, using a content type ID does work but using a content type ID requires modifying the display template for every SharePoint deployment.

Comment: Try to use "White_x0020_Paper" instead.

Comment: Using "White_x0020_Paper" doesn't work either..

Comment: My last suggestion would be to try "Whitex0020Paper", then i'm out of ideas.